# Class creating multiple objects of another class at the same memory location (C++)

Tags: c++

So, I've got this class that contains a vector of another class. Whenever I try to push a new object into this vector, it's creating that object at the same memory location each time.

The (hopefully) relevant code:

```
class FSM{
    private:
        std::vector<Node> nodeList;
        int cap;
        int obs;
        int topNode;

    public:
        FSM(int nodeCap, int numObs){
            cap = nodeCap;
            obs = numObs;
            topNode = -1;
        }

        bool addNode(){
            if (isFull()) return false;
            nodeList.push_back(Node(obs));
            topNode++;
            return true;
        }
```

Now, if I create a stand-alone Node object in my main function and cout the &node, I get different memory locations. But the ones created in the FSM class are always the same. Also, if I change anything in one of the Nodes stored by the FSM class, it changes it for all of them. I have no idea what's going on.

EDIT: As requested, here is the Node class. Just gonna post the whole thing, not sure what is relevant.

```
class Node{
    private:
        std::vector<int> connects;
        int action;

    public:
        Node(int numObs){
            for(int i = 0; i < numObs; i++){
                connects.push_back(-1);
            }
            srand(time(NULL));
        }

        void setConnections(std::vector<int> newVec){
            for (int i = 0; i < connects.size(); i++){
                connects[i] = newVec[i];
            }
        }

        int getConnection(int index){
            return connects[index];
        }

        std::vector<int> getConnectionList(){
            return connects;
        }

        void setAction(int act){
            action = act;
        }

        int getAction(){
            return action;
        }

        void setRandomConnections(int numNodes){
            for (int i = 0; i < connects.size(); i++){
                connects[i] = rand() % numNodes;
            }
        }
};
```

EDIT the Second: Here's what my main is doing.

```
int main(){
FSM myFSM(5, 3);
while (!myFSM.isFull()){
    myFSM.addNode();
    std::cout << &myFSM.getTopNode(); // getTopNode() returns the most recent
                                              // node.
}
}
```

Comment: Can we see the Node class?

Comment: Yep, let me add that.

Comment: So are you pushing multiple nodes to the vector? Or are you just re-running your program several times?

Comment: In the main I'm running a while loop that calls addNode until the FSM is full.

Comment: Can we see the code that obtains a `Node` in order to display its address?  I suspect that this code is where the problem lies.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce your claim that all the nodes are in the same memory location](https://ideone.com/RXlZ7N)

Comment: Can you post a minimal main() that reproduces this by printing out the addresses?

Comment: Added the basic main() where the Node creation is being done.

Comment: I think the problem is in the code that is supposed to get the top node.

Comment: If getTopNode does what I think it does, you're printing the address of a temporary object (aka a *copy* of the top node, not the top node itself). So that code is meaningless.

Comment: Please also post the getTopNode() code.

Comment: @Borgleader make that an answer, I'm almost certain you're right.

Comment: Show code that can be copied, pasted, compiled and run. It isn't anyone's idea of fun to reconstruct all the little missing bits.

Comment: In `Node`'s constructor, try std::cout << (int)this;

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in the title of questions in this site. Whether a question is answered or not is already indicated by the icon next to it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If getTopNode does what I think it does, you're printing the address of a temporary object (aka a copy of the top node, not the top node itself). So that code is meaningless.

[Here](https://ideone.com/RXlZ7N) I've implemented a print function for the locations of the nodes in FSM:

```
void printNodeLocations()
{
    for(Node& n : nodeList) { std::cout << &n << std::endl; }
}
```

And I get different ones as expected:

```
0x8ad3018
0x8ad301c
```

EDIT: I cannot reproduce your claim that changing one node changes all of them. [See updated code](https://ideone.com/qfH35C)

Comment: Hmm...Let me check that out. I think I might know the issue with the node changing thing, but I think you're right here.

Comment: @MRoush I've added an update code sample where I change one of the node's values. The other node(s) are not affected.

Comment: Yeah, this was the issue. I think the other issue is also a print error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
std::cout << &myFSM.getTopNode();
```

probably prints the address of a temporary object, not the actual object in the vector. This will be true if you're not returning by reference but rather by value.

So it's not weird if the temporary happens to be created at the same location each time, since after the temporary dies, its location in memory is free to be used again later.

In order to get the actual object rather than a copy of it, getTopNode() needs to do:

```
Node& FSM::getTopNode()
{
    if (nodeList.empty()) {
        // Up to you how to handle this error.
    }
    return nodeList.back();
}
```

Of course, if your current getTopNode() implementation actually already returns a pointer:

```
Node* FSM::getTopNode()
```

then your problem is that you're printing out the address of the pointer rather than the pointer itself. In that case you should print with:

```
std::cout << myFSM.getTopNode();
```

Comment: True, but it doesn't explain this assertion from the original question: "if I change anything in one of the Nodes stored by the FSM class, it changes it for all of them."

Comment: It doesn't. You cannot take an address of a temporary.

Comment: @n.m. You can do that with some compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens similar to yours.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Node{
    private:
        std::vector<int> connects;
        int action;

    public:
        Node(int num){
            for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
                connects.push_back(i);
            }

        }
    std::vector<int> getConn()
    {
        return connects;
    }
};

class FSM{
    private:
        std::vector<Node> nodeList;
    public:
        FSM(){}
    void addNode(int size){
        Node l(size);
        std::cout<<"temp_address "<<&l<<"\n";   
        nodeList.push_back(l);//use of default copy constructor
    }
    void printList(){
        std::vector<int> p;
        for (int i=0; i<nodeList.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout<<"Node_arr_num "<<i<<" mem_address "<<&nodeList[i]<<"\nConnections:";
            p=nodeList[i].getConn();
            for (int j=0; j<p.size(); j++)
                std::cout<<" "<<p[j];   
            std::cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
FSM f;
f.addNode(5);
f.addNode(10);
f.addNode(3);
f.printList();
return 0;
}
```

[Result:](https://ideone.com/s9QXLf)

```
temp_address 0xbfea7660
temp_address 0xbfea7660
temp_address 0xbfea7660
Node_arr_num 0 mem_address 0x8dab098
Connections: 0 1 2 3 4
Node_arr_num 1 mem_address 0x8dab0a8
Connections: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Node_arr_num 2 mem_address 0x8dab0b8
Connections: 0 1 2
```

Be careful with adding nodes later, when your app will grow. Temporary `l` object (ore your `Node(obs)`) must be copied with explicit copy constructor of class `Node` if `Node` will be more complex (contains fields with dynamic allocated memory).